# find number of days for given month and year in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get number of days for given month and year in node.js

npm i date-and-time is install in node

```
dailyCalibRptTempTbl(req){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let responseObj = {};
        var str_date = req.body.date;
        var year = str_date.split('-')[0];
        var month = str_date.split('-')[1];
        var day = this.getNumOfDays(year,month);
        console.log(day);
    })
}

getNumOfDays(y,m){
    var days = date(y, m, 0).getDate();
    return days;
}
```

expect then in 31 days for month 3 and year 2019

Comment: You can use `moment-js` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/utilities/ for date time manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new Date` as like below

```
function getNumOfDays(y, m) {
    return new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Moment js It is very easy to find the number of days in a given month.

Suppose your date format is 2019-03-30
you want to know the number of days in 2019-03

```
const moment = require('moment')

moment('2019-03', 'YYYY-MM').daysInMonth()
```

For Number of days in a given year, Check if the given year is a leap year or not, if it is a leap year, number of days = 366, else 365.

```
let isLeapYear = moment([2019]).isLeapYear()

let numOfDaysInYear = 365
if(isLeapYear){
  numOfDayInYear = 366
}
```